# Public Dns forwared

Tags: dns-hosting

i wish every one was fine ,, i have issue , the issue is 
if i have DNS Server (Public ) let say the ip DNS 10.10.0.1(xx.com) and i have another Server it have Public Ip Let say 10.10.0.2 And i installation Nat Service all traffic forward (VM) to Zimbra exchange Email s, i create the mx record on dns public mail.xx.com and the ip address (10.10.0.2) (public server) to forward traffic when i nslookup everything is good but from VM ZIMBRA Can not resolved mx record and i can send email but i can't receive any email from other

Comment: I don't think we can answer this unless you either vastly improve the English (sorry), or (better) tell us the real domain name and IPs.  With what we've got here, it's *extremely* difficult to work out what your problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I gather, you have your server that hosts your domain on one server and your Zimbra Mail server on another. To work, Zimbra needs two DNS entries for this type of setup. Something like this:

```
MX record: "example.com    MX    0    zmail.example.com"
A record:  "zmail          A          XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
```

If you've set these up and you can verify DNS elsewhere (through a dig or something), it's a configuration error on the Zimbra server if you're still not receiving.